# Create table using the datestamp

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to create a table using current date stamp? I want the format of date stamp to be

> MM/DD/YYYY

Let's say I want to use that format: what is the exact code for that?
Instead of table, I want to use that datestamp to be my database name?

Comment: No, you don't want to store that format. SQLite doesn't have native date/time types, it prefers to use ISO8601 formatted strings so you should store dates in `text` fields as `YYYY-MM-DD` and deal with any format conversions in your app.

Comment: Valid SQLite data formats: [SQLite TimeStrings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Okay, Lets say i want to put that format, What is the exact code for that? Instead of table, i want to use that datestamp to be my database_name? Please help me :(

Comment: Comments are not meant for asking additional questions.  Please update your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of table, i want to use that datestamp to be my database_name?

Never a good idea to put data of high volatility as a database name. (You do not want a brand new database for every day of every year).

You can add one column to your table(s), and [it must be `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, or `REAL`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype).

If using `TEXT`, [only **certain formats** work correctly](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). `MM/DD/YYYY` is not one of those formats because `06/12/1945` would be **before** `07/05/2014`